# Webform preview page

Tags: webforms

I have a Multistep Webform. I have put Captcha in Preview page.
But when i click "previous" button in preview page then Captcha asking for validation.

How do i remove captcha validation when i click previous button.
And also how to put "term and condition" field in preview page.

Answer (score 1):

There are known issues with the CAPTCHA module on multi-step forms. https://www.google.com/search?q=drupal+captcha+multistep+form.

You can create a custom preview page by placing a Computed Twig/Token Element on the last page of a multi-step form.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for reply.can you tell me how to create custom preview page with all entered data field?

Comment: Create a multi-step form and on the last page place a Computed Token Element which contains the [webform_submission:values] token